# How to call child function which is declared inside another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

Function b is declared inside function a. So, i am trying to call function b  outside function a. It is not getting called.

```
var a = function() {
  alert("a");
  var b = function() {
    alert("b");
  }
}
```

Output:-
function b called
Alert box with message b

Comment: you can't do it. That's what scope is all about. If you want `b` to be callable from outside the function, you need to declare it outside the function. (Or alternatively, use a closure to return something from `a` that includes a reference to `b`.) Without knowing the use case, it's hard to give recommendations - but for the toy example, simply making `b` a global function should be fine.

Comment: this is sample code. Here the situation is i cant declare outside because of some callback case. Will you please show me the global thing.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to return `b` and use that. This will involve calling the function `a` to begin with, but then you'd have a function which you could call repeatedly to alert `b`:

```js
var a = function() {
  alert("a");
  var b = function() {
    alert("b");
  }
  return b;
}

var messageB = a();
messageB();
messageB();
```

Comment: Here alert a is also called which i don't need. Whenever function b is call then i need only b as alert.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar You can't fix that - you call `a`, which after running the code (`alert("a")`) returns another function which can be called repeatedly to alert `b`. Unless you change the code inside `a`, you cannot escape the `alert("a")` being called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare 'b' variable outside 'a' function:

```
var b;
var a = function() {
    alert("a");
    b = function() {
        alert("b");
    };
};
```

That way, you can access `b` from outside of `a` as it is declared outside of it. Before `a` was called the first time, it will be `undefined` though, so you can't call `b` before `a`. Additionally if you call `a` twice, the previous `b` will be overriden., as shown here:

```
  var b;

  var a = function(name) {
    b = function() { alert(name); };
  };

  a("first version");
  b(); // first version
  a("second version");
  b(); // second version
```

If you don't need any inner variables from `a` inside `b`, there is no reason to nest the functions though, in that case you should just have two independent functions:

```
  var a = function() { alert("a"); };
  var b = function() { alert("b"); };
```

Comment: Hello Kirill, welcome to SO, before posting an answer please take a look at [answer]

Answer (score 0):

First return that function and call it,

```js
var a = function() {
  alert("a");
  var b = function() {
    alert("b");
  }
  return b;
}

var b = a();
b();
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can simply return function b.  Functions in Javascript can be passed around like this, it's a very nice feature of a garbage collected language.

But you can go even better, what if you wanted to expose more than one function.

You can just return an object with methods attached.

```js
function A() {
  let value = 0;
  return {
    inc: () => ++ value,
    dec: () => -- value,
    show: () => console.log(value)
  }
}

const a1 = A();
a1.inc(); a1.inc(); a1.show();

const b1 = A();
b1.inc(); b1.dec(); b1.dec(); b1.show();
```

Now the above looks very similar to what's called a `class` but it's not.  One disadvantage to this is if you wanted to create thousands of instances, a class would be better as that can put it's methods on the prototype.   But saying that, as has been found using React Hooks it's not really that bad then.

One big advantage of the above, is you don't have to get into the muddy world of `this` context of instances.

For completeness here is a class version.

```js
class A {
  value = 0;
  inc() { ++ this.value; }
  dec() { -- this.value; }
  show() { console.log(this.value) }
};

const a1 = new A();
a1.inc(); a1.inc(); a1.show();

const b1 = new A();
b1.inc(); b1.dec(); b1.dec(); b1.show();
```

It was also said a simple solution is to make `a` and `b` both global, but the more you avoid the global the better, so if `a` and `b` have some common intent, using closures or even a class would be better.

Answer (score 0):

or if you would need object approch

```
`var a = function() {
  print("a");
  this.b = function() {
    print("b");
  }
  return this
}
a().b()`
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answer's are great enough, but just in case you may like this approach of `directly calling` `inner function` `without returning` that function.

You can simply wrap your inner function i.e `b` in your case, as a self invoking function like this,

```
var a = function() {
  alert("a");
  var b = (function() {
    alert("b");
  })()
}
```

[Ref](https://idiallo.com/javascript/self-invoking-anonymous-function)